# Border to stop reducing size when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, accordion

I'm working on an accordion. I've used jQuery for the animation. When I click on the accordion head the border that holds the `+` reduces in size. I only want the plus sign to change and the border to stay the same size.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //toggle the component with class accordion_body
  $(".accordion_head").click(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('coll-back');
    if ($('.accordion_body').is(':visible')) {
      $(".accordion_body").slideUp(400);
      $("plusminus").text('+');
      $(this).removeClass('coll-back');
      $('.rmv-cls').removeClass('coll-back');
    }

    if ($(this).next(".accordion_body").is(':visible')) {
      $(this).next(".accordion_body").slideUp(400);
      $(this).children("plusminus").text('+');
      $(this).removeClass('coll-back');
    } else {
      $(this).next(".accordion_body").slideDown(400);
      $(this).children("plusminus").text('');
      $(this).children("plusminus").append('<hr class="hr-clc">');
      $(this).toggleClass('coll-back');
      $(this).addClass('rmv-cls');
    }
  });
});

$('plusminus').on("click", function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  $(this).text() == "+" ? $(this).text("-") : $(this).text("+");
});
```

```css
.plusminus {
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #139c4b;
  color: #fff;
  margin-left: 13px;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
}

#plus-1 {
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
  left: -27%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="start">
  <div class="acc-main">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="kind">
        <div class="accordion_container">
          <div class="accordion-main">
            <div class="accordion_head"><span class="plusminus" id="plus-1">+</span>Because She Matters
            </div>
            <div class="accordion_body" id="a1" style="display: none;">
              <p class="para-acc"> 
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The font used has its characters with different width, that is the characters + and - have different width. So when they switch, it affects the total width of the block.
You can solve it using a monospaced font, such as Monospace, Courier, Courier New or Lucida Console.

Another solution would be set a fixed `width` for the block.
First, the `<span>` must be an block element. You add to it `display: inline-block`. Then padding will be considered within total width as default, so you have 25px padding for left and right. Your block is about 72px (when +), then you can add `width: 22px` (50px + 22px = 72px fixed width).

```
.plusminus {
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #139c4b;
  color: #fff;
  margin-left: 13px;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
  display: inline-block; /* add this */ 
  width: 22px; /* add this */
}
```

A little bit the height of the accordion head will change with that, but nothing big.

Comment: Hi, thanks it worked, right now I can only click on the plus border for it to morph into a minus but i want it to morph a minus when you click the accordion head. https://codepen.io/Kerv/pen/KKppVpo

Comment: Glad it worked for you.
The border is inside the ``.accordion_head``, so you can migrate the click morph function from the border to the ``.accordion_head``. Then when you click either the border or accordion, it will change the plus/minus.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following css code

```
.plusminus {
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    line-height: 70px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Fixed it, for you for the help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You have already added `.active` class to `.plusmimus` class on click of the accordion. I have added some extra `CSS` code to make it look better as you required.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.plusminus').on("click", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.plusminus {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #139c4b;
  color: #fff;
  margin-left: 13px;
  padding: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

.plusminus::before,
.plusminus::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 16px;
  height: 2px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #FFF;
  transition: 0.15s ease-out all;
}
.plusminus::after {
  width: 2px;
  height: 16px;
}
.plusminus.active::before {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.plusminus.active::after {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="plusminus"></span>
```

Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thank you, it's not the type of animation I was looking for but this helped a lot too.